# Rename job in Folder 2 changes job name in Copy Artifact plugin in a job in Folder 1

Tags: jenkins, copy, directory, cloudbees

I think I may have found a bug in either the Copy Artifacts plug-in or the Folders plug-in...

If I change a job name in one folder it causes a configuration change to a job in a different folder.

I am using the Folders plug-in and the Copy Artifact plugin.

I recreated this issue in a clean Jenkins server with the Folders and Copy Artifacts plug-ins installed as follows:
1. Create a folder: Folder 1
2. Create a job: Job 1.  This job creates and archives a text file: job1.txt  (Windows batch step: echo %JOB_NAME% > job1.txt)
3. Create a second job: Job 2.  Configure Job 2 to use the Copy Artifact plug-in to get the job1.txt artifact from Job 1.
4. Run Job 1.  The job1.txt file is created and archived
5. Run Job 2.  The job1.txt file is successfully retrieved from Job 1.

1. Copy Folder 1 to Folder 1. (Create a new job Folder 2 and copy existing job Folder 1).
   Folder 2 is created containing Job 1 and Job 2.
2. Rename Folder 2; Job 1 (to Job 1 Renamed)
3. The Copy Artifact reference in Folder 2; Job 2 is changed as expected.
4. Inspect Folder 1; Job 2.  The Copy Artifact reference has also changed.  This is not as expected.

Glenn

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug in Copy Artifact; did you confirm against trunk (since there have been a bunch of unreleased changes) and file it?

Comment: I did not.  I guess I'd need to build from source.  I've not done that for a Jenkins plug-in before.  I'll see if I can do it.